# ¿Cómo mostrar una validación con sessions de JSP?

Tags: java, web

Cordial saludo

Buenos días; estoy realizando un login y quiero mostrar si el usuario escribe mal el usuario o clave. Muestra algo así:

[image]

Aparece a pesar de que no he realizado ninguna acción en el controlador, solo refresqué la página y me salió esto.

El código utilizado en el formulario es

```
<%
   if(request.getAttribute("usuario")!=null){
       if(request.getAttribute("usuario")=="1"){
           HttpSession Usuario = request.getSession();
           Usuario.setAttribute("usuario", request.getAttribute("usuario"));
       }
   }else{
       out.print("<div class='text-danger text-center'>Usuario y/o Clave incorrecta!</div>");
   }
%>
```

y este es el código en el controlador

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    if (accion.equals("ingresar")) {

        String usuario = request.getParameter("email");
        //String nombrecompleto =request.getParameter(dao.getUsuarios("name"));
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");

        user.setCorreo(usuario);


        user.setPassword(pass);
        r = dao.validarUsuario(user);
        if (r == 1) {

            request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
            //request.getSession().setAttribute("nom", nombrecompleto);
            //request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario",nombre);
            response.sendRedirect("administrador/index.jsp");
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("administrador/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aparece porque en el else no tienes ninguna condición para mostrar es mensaje.

Yo separaría ese if, y obtendría un mensaje desde le controlador.
Así puedes tener varios mensajes dependendiendo del resultado del controlador. Ovbiamente hay más opciones. También podrías hacerlo con Ajax.

Te comparto una forma de hacerlo:

```
<%
   if(request.getAttribute("usuario")!=null){
       if(request.getAttribute("usuario")=="1"){
           HttpSession Usuario = request.getSession();
           Usuario.setAttribute("usuario", 
           request.getAttribute("usuario"));
       }
   }

    String mensaje = request.getParameter("mensaje");// este mensaje 
                                                viene del controlador

    switch(mensaje){
        case "1":
        out.print("<div class='text-danger text-center'>Usuario y/o 
             Clave incorrecta!</div>");     
        break;
        case "2":
        out.print("<div class='text-danger text-center'>Usuario no 
             registrado</div>");     
        break;
        
    }

    
 %>
```

Comment: gracias por tu colaboración como quedaria en el controlador esta arriba anexe el codigo del controlador, muchas gracias por su colaboración